# How to show alphabetical letters on side of Android ListView

Tags: android, listview

I've looked at a lot of tutorials for making a ListView have the alphabetical letters on the side (like the Contacts list), but they all seem to using a ListActivity class and/or data from a database while I'm just using a ListView (no special Activity) and an ArrayList of data. Does anyone know how I can implement that alphabetical-scroll feature in the Contacts list for my own ListView?

**Edited Again**

I followed [this tutorial](http://web.archive.org/web/20151120011714/http://twistbyte.com:80/tutorial/android-listview-with-fast-scroll-and-section-index), which I thought would finally make it work, but I'm still getting a forced close.

```
class AlphabeticalAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> implements SectionIndexer
{
    private HashMap<String, Integer> alphaIndexer;
    private String[] sections;

    public AlphabeticalAdapter(Context c, int resource, List<String> data)
    {
        super(c, resource, data);
        for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++)
        {
            String s = data.get(i).substring(0, 1).toUpperCase();
            alphaIndexer.put(s, i);
        }

        Set<String> sectionLetters = alphaIndexer.keySet();
        ArrayList<String> sectionList = new ArrayList<String>(sectionLetters);
        Collections.sort(sectionList);
        sections = new String[sectionList.size()];
        sectionList.toArray(sections);

    }

    public int getPositionForSection(int section)
    {   
        return alphaIndexer.get(sections[section]);
    }

    public int getSectionForPosition(int position)
    {
        return 1;
    }

    public Object[] getSections()
    {
        return sections;
    }
}
```

In the LogCat, it says `java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {(package of another app I made) android.app.SuperNotCalledExcpetion`. I thought that was really weird because I don't reference that other app at all in the one I'm working with. I tried uninstalling that other app, still got the forced close, but I could see what the LogCat said because it didn't update.

**Final Edit**

Here is the working code. Sorry for posting it something like 9 months overdue.

```
class AlphabeticalAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> implements SectionIndexer
{
    private HashMap<String, Integer> alphaIndexer;
    private String[] sections;

    public AlphabeticalAdapter(Context c, int resource, List<String> data)
    {
        super(c, resource, data);
        alphaIndexer = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++)
        {
            String s = data.get(i).substring(0, 1).toUpperCase();
            if (!alphaIndexer.containsKey(s))
                alphaIndexer.put(s, i);
        }

        Set<String> sectionLetters = alphaIndexer.keySet();
        ArrayList<String> sectionList = new ArrayList<String>(sectionLetters);
        Collections.sort(sectionList);
        sections = new String[sectionList.size()];
        for (int i = 0; i < sectionList.size(); i++)
            sections[i] = sectionList.get(i);   
    }

    public int getPositionForSection(int section)
    {   
        return alphaIndexer.get(sections[section]);
    }

    public int getSectionForPosition(int position)
    {
        for ( int i = sections.length - 1; i >= 0; i-- ) {
            if ( position >= alphaIndexer.get( sections[ i ] ) ) {
                return i;
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }

    public Object[] getSections()
    {
        return sections;
    }
}
```

Edit : getSectionForPosition is important if you want your scroller appear in the right place while you are scrolling. Returning only 1 (or 0) tells that you are just scrolling in the first (or second) section which will result in scroller's wrong position (mostly goes out of screen). Added code returns the appropriate section so scroller can know where it actually is.

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to use ListActivity?  Can you link to the tutorials you speak of?

Comment: to get the first letter of the word

Comment: I tried substring(0, 1), still didn't work

Comment: change getSectionForPosition to return 0; I get smoother scrolling at the bottom of the listview with that

Comment: can you please post the whole code i implement it but it is not working for me i will be really thankful

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I forgot to instantiate `alphaIndexer`. Works perfectly now.

```
class AlphabeticalAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> implements SectionIndexer
{
    private HashMap<String, Integer> alphaIndexer;
    private String[] sections;

    public AlphabeticalAdapter(Context c, int resource, List<String> data)
    {
        super(c, resource, data);
        alphaIndexer = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++)
        {
            String s = data.get(i).substring(0, 1).toUpperCase();
            if (!alphaIndexer.containsKey(s))
                alphaIndexer.put(s, i);
        }

        Set<String> sectionLetters = alphaIndexer.keySet();
        ArrayList<String> sectionList = new ArrayList<String>(sectionLetters);
        Collections.sort(sectionList);
        sections = new String[sectionList.size()];
        for (int i = 0; i < sectionList.size(); i++)
            sections[i] = sectionList.get(i);   
    }

    public int getPositionForSection(int section)
    {   
        return alphaIndexer.get(sections[section]);
    }

    public int getSectionForPosition(int position)
    {
        return 1;
    }

    public Object[] getSections()
    {
        return sections;
    }
}
```

Comment: @Pat: Hello i also want the final working demo if you have completed it. Thanks.

Comment: @akdurmus sorry for the long delay.

Comment: @Pat Nice one, really hard to find a proper tutorial on this subject but this worked out of the box. Thanks

Comment: guys i have used the above adapter, but its not showing any alphabets to the right ... is anything that i am missing

Comment: What version of Android does your phone/emulator use, and which version are you targeting? That might make I difference

Comment: @PatNeedham the alphabets are not showing up for me...do we need to add anything to my listview xml file...or the above is sufficient for the alphabets to show up??

Comment: One improvement would be to use a collator: Collator coll = Collator.getInstance(); coll.setStrength(Collator.TERTIARY); Collections.sort(sectionList, coll);

Answer (score 3):

If I understand you correctly, you want to set `fastScrollEnabled=true` and that will give you the little thumb scroller on the right.  If you want to add a floating letter like the one in contacts, there is a great example in the APIDemos project in List9.java (http://www.devdaily.com/java/jwarehouse/android-examples/platforms/android-2/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/List9.java.shtml)

Comment: I think they are asking for actually seeing A, B, C, etc, similar to the iPhone contacts list UI.  A custom scrollbar widget type thing.

Comment: There's a section and a visible dialog during scroll. And fastScrollEnabled is set to true on ListView.