# Android listview with sectionHeader and index both

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

[image]

like this view in Iphone ,i need to design the view for android.A list view contain both section Index and section Header.Please help.

Comment: Here is the answer to your question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8192683/how-to-create-an-alphabetical-scrollbar-displaying-all-the-letter-in-android

Comment: some more urls to understand better...
http://twistbyte.com/tutorial/android-listview-with-fast-scroll-and-section-index

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7129069/how-to-show-alphabetical-letters-on-side-of-android-listview

Comment: but the list view contain index and Header text both,if there is any sample application please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try installing this app, i am most certain that there is a library project present in the app. 
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.groidify.uipatterns

Just a suggestion in case of Android the above could be accomplished by using a merge adapter by commonsware and sectionIndexer.

The closest one and smoothest would be
https://github.com/woozzu/indexableListView

Comment: The link at the end (indexableListView) demonstrates section indices and fast scrolling, but NOT section headers...