# How to get a spinner with alphabets to sort from on the right hand side

Tags: android, android-spinner

Is it possible to build a spinner like the one in android contacts? I have a huge list for a spinner to choose from. And I want user comfortably select from the list by providing a list of alphabets on the right hand side of the spinner dropdown. Just like the one we see in contacts. How can I do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/q/7129069/1069068

Comment: I don't think this is possible for a Spinner, at least not via the standard API. You'd have to roll your own SectionIndexer (as linked to by @RaghavSood) and implement that into a custom Spinner. Not for the faint of heart. I'm thinking Spinner is a poor choice of widget for what you're doing. Try a list dialog or something like that instead.