# SectionIndexer - Using with ArrayAdapter and CustomObject?

Tags: android, arraylist, android-listview, android-arrayadapter

I am following a great coding example over here: [This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7129069/how-to-show-alphabetical-letters-on-side-of-android-listview). It is regarding implementing a SectionIndexer interface to an array adapter.

However, how would you do the same thing if your ArrayAdapter is passing an ArrayList< MyObject > not an ArrayList< String >?

For example, this is where my code is different then his code.  He has:

```
class AlphabeticalAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> implements SectionIndexer {
private HashMap<String, Integer> alphaIndexer;
private String[] sections;

public AlphabeticalAdapter(Context c, int resource, List<String> data) {

    alphaIndexer = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++) {
        String s = data.get(i).substring(0, 1).toUpperCase();
        alphaIndexer.put(s, i);
    }

    // other stuff

 }
```

I am having problems adapting that for loop to my situation.  I can't measure the size like he does.  Where he has the above, my adapter begins with.

```
 public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Items> implements
    SectionIndexer {

     public ItemAdapter(Context context, Items[] objects) {
```

Where he is passing one ArrayList, I have to pass in three, but to make that happen, had to wrap in a custom object class.  One of the ArrayLists that I want to sort is one of three fields in the class called "name".  It is a string obviously.

I want to scroll through that alphabetically with SectionIndex based on that name field.  How do I change the example code from the other question to work in this scenario?

Where he has "data.size()", I need something like "name.size()"  - I think?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Where he is passing one ArrayList, I have to pass in three, but to
>   make that happen, had to wrap in a custom object class. One of the
>   ArrayLists that I want to sort is one of three fields in the class
>   called "name".

You don't have three `ArrayLists`, you have an `ArrayList` of custom objects that were built from three `ArrayLists`(so the size is the size of the `List` that you pass to the adapter). From this point of view the only change in your code is to use the *name* from that custom object `Items` to build the sections:

```
for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++) {
    String s = data.get(i).name.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase();
    if (!alphaIndexer.containsKey(s)) {
        alphaIndexer.put(s, i);
    }
}
// ...
```

There aren't other changes. Also you may need to sort the `List` of `Items` that you pass to the adapter using:

```
Collections.sort(mData);
```

where your `Items` class must implement the `Comparable<Items>` interface:

```
    class Items implements Comparable<Items> {
        String name;
        // ... rest of the code

        @Override
        public int compareTo(Items another) {   
            // I assume that you want to sort the data after the name field of the Items class
            return name.compareToIgnoreCase(another.name);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Hey thanks!  I edited my code showing one other part that I should have included.  I added my Adapter's constructor.  I'm actually passing an Array of objects, not ArrayLists, which I believe changes the for loop again?

Comment: @KickingLettuce The only change is the syntax to get the size of the data, instead of `data.size()` you would use `data.length` because you use an array.

Comment: Thanks again.  I did figure that one out through the help of Eclipse.  However, it gave me no recommendations on this:  'data.get(i).name.substring(0, 1)'  That was the only error I was getting.  I figured it would be data[i].name.substring(0,1) but I think it had a problem on that as well.

Comment: @KickingLettuce Yeap, I forgot about that. It should be(just to see) `Items it = data[i]; String name = it.name; String section = name.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase();// ...`. Do you get any errors?

Comment: I will try this later this evening and get back to you.  Thanks!  It does look solid to me.  I will mark correct once I get this working, for now, I am +1'ing everything.

Comment: I had same problem your answer helped. i had to implement in already created custom adapter and this peace of code helped a lot. thanks!!