# IndexOutOfBoundsException in a BaseExpandableListAdapter implementing SectionIndexer

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I have created an alphabetical adapter, inspiring from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7129069/how-to-show-alphabetical-letters-on-side-of-android-listview) with the adding of headers and for an expandableListView.
Each group of my list have exactly one child.

Sometimes, and for reason that I don't understand, Android give me an IndexOutOfBoundsException with the getPositionForSection method. The section called is out of bound of the my sections string array. I think it's because of the expandable list but I'm not sure. Can you help me ?

```
public class AlphabeticalAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter implements SectionIndexer{

private HashMap<String, Integer> alphaIndexer;
private String[] sections;
private HashMap<String, String> dictionnary;
private ArrayList<String> words;
private LayoutInflater inflater;

public AlphabeticalAdapter(Context context, HashMap<String, String> dictionnary){

    this.inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    this.dictionnary = dictionnary;
    this.words = new ArrayList<String>(this.dictionnary.keySet());
    Collections.sort(this.words, String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);

    this.alphaIndexer = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    for (int i = 0; i < this.words.size(); i++){
        String s = this.words.get(i).substring(0, 1).toUpperCase();
        if (!this.alphaIndexer.containsKey(s)){
            this.alphaIndexer.put(s, i);
        }
    }

    Set<String> sectionLetters = this.alphaIndexer.keySet();
    ArrayList<String> sectionList = new ArrayList<String>(sectionLetters);
    Collections.sort(sectionList);

    this.sections = new String[sectionList.size()];
    for (int i = 0; i < sectionList.size(); i++){
        this.sections[i] = sectionList.get(i);
    }

}

@Override
public int getSectionForPosition(int position){

    String currentFirstChar = this.words.get(position).substring(0, 1).toUpperCase();
    for (int section = 0; section < this.sections.length; section++){
        if (this.sections[section].equals(currentFirstChar)){
            return section;
        }
    }

    return 1;

}

@Override
public int getPositionForSection(int section){
    return this.alphaIndexer.get(this.sections[section]);   
}

@Override
public Object[] getSections(){
    return this.sections;
}

@Override
public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
    return this.words.get(groupPosition);
}

@Override
public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return this.dictionnary.get(getGroup(groupPosition));
}

@Override
public int getGroupCount() {
    return this.dictionnary.size();
}

@Override
public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
    return 1;
}

@Override
public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
    return groupPosition;
}

@Override
public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return childPosition;
}

@Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
        View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View view = (View) inflater.inflate(R.layout.glossary_word_row, null);

    TextView header = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.section);
    TextView rowText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView);

    String currentWord = this.words.get(groupPosition);
    String currentFirstChar = currentWord.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase();

    rowText.setText(currentWord);

    if (groupPosition == this.alphaIndexer.get(currentFirstChar)){
        header.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        header.setText(currentFirstChar);
    }

    return view;

}

@Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition,
        boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View view = (View) this.inflater.inflate(R.layout.glossary_word_row, null);
    TextView rowText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView);
    rowText.setText(this.dictionnary.get(this.words.get(groupPosition)));

    return view;

}

@Override
public boolean hasStableIds() {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return false;
}

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't understand why this method is called with wrong parameter, but I have seen in [the official Android documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SectionIndexer.html) this :

> Returns : the starting position of that section. If the section is out of bounds, the     position must be clipped to fall within the size of the list.

So I have write this :

```
@Override
public int getPositionForSection(int section){
    if (section >= this.sections.length){
        return getGroupCount() - 1;
    }
    return this.alphaIndexer.get(this.sections[section]);   
}
```

And all is working well. Problem solved :-)